# Cakephp 3.0 I would like to include a Year input field with a drop down, but it is inputing as an array

Tags: cakephp-3.0, formhelper

I have a Year field in a form and I am using FormHelper.

```
            echo $this->Form->input('year', [
                            'type' => 'year',
            'minYear' => date('Y')-10,
            'maxYear' => date('Y')
        ]);
```

The table file validator looks like:

```
            ->add('year', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('year')
```

I have a very similar input in another app that seems to work fine. I set the MySql column to int(5) to match what I had working elsewhere.

Checking debugkit it shows the "year" input as an array while the other inputs are strings. If I remove the validation rule it throws an illegal array to string conversion, so I assume this is where the error is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested with your above code and it is working fine for me. Try to delete the cache and check it once more.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried with a different browser and I am getting the same result. I add more components to my post to hopefully find what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Creates a select element populated with the years from minYear to maxYear. Additionally, HTML attributes may be supplied in $options. If $options['empty'] is false, the select will not include an empty option:

- empty - If true, the empty select option is shown. If a string, that
  string is displayed as the empty element.
- orderYear - Ordering of
  year values in select options. Possible values ‘asc’, ‘desc’. Default
  ‘desc’ value The selected value of the input.
- maxYear The max year to
  appear in the select element.
- minYear The min year to appear in the
  select element.

Try this one:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->year('exp_date', [
    'minYear'   => date('Y')-10,
    'maxYear'   => date('Y'),
    'id'        => 'cc-year',
    'class'     => 'form-control',
    'empty'     => false,
    'orderYear' => 'asc'
]);
?>
```

Official Documentation: [CookBook - Creating Year Inputs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-year-inputs)